# Finding a way to create a HTTPS REST api connection through ip address (incl SSL cert)

Tags: node.js, rest, express, ssl, vue.js

I need help with finding a method to create a SSL cert for my IP address so that I can use the REST api between my frontend Vue and backend Express.

NGINX is the web server. And it serves the frontend and it redirects the connection to HTTPS with SSL cert from Let's Encrypt. However there is a mixed protocol error when the frontend connects with the backend as it is served through HTTP.

My workaround was to create a HTTPS server for the Express files. But I needed a SSL cert to validate the HTTPS server for Express and there are no SSL cert that is free for the address used to serve the Express files, which is the IP address. Some suggested using self-signed but they are only useful for development and now I am trying to use it for production.

Comment: You don't need to run express as an HTTPS server, the reverse proxy (NGiNX) will secure the connection. The code that runs in the browser is likely using absolute URLs (e.g. `http://<host>/path/to/resource`), you want to use relative URLs so that the browser remains in the current context (e.g. `/path/to/resource`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ssl certs which work for nginx also work for express.

If you are running Express only, then you can drop nginx completely and use https on express with the let's encrypt certs.

Otherwise if you have an exotic configuration, then you can configure nginx as an ssl reverse proxy using proxy redirect to change the protocol. https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2011/12/21/nginx-ssl-reverse-proxy-tutorial.html

Comment: This is actually not true. NGiNX requires the certificate chain in a special format (See [SSL certificate chains](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) section). Node.js accepts the certificate chain as it's own argument to the SSL context (See the [ca](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options) option).

Comment: @Jake i have the exact setup the OP is using. Let's encrypt / express. If he can get it working with nginx, i can get it working with Express, then they are compatible. And i most definitely didn't figure it out myself. https://itnext.io/node-express-letsencrypt-generate-a-free-ssl-certificate-and-run-an-https-server-in-5-minutes-a730fbe528ca. Also read this : https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-get-crt-and-key-files-from-i-just-have-pem-files/7348/3

Comment: So you're also using NGiNX as a reverse proxy? I was merely pointing out that there are indeed differences, they are not configured exactly the same.

Comment: Hey but the issue is that the certs from Lets Encrypt do not work for IP addresses. So I cant use the certs for NGINX or Express

Comment: @eng heng i thought you already have a nginx server working? Ip address certs are not cheap. If doing dev work, either self sign and trust or get a free domain name and use let's encrypt.